# MVC5 block Action from all but localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, http-status-code-403

I looked for a solution to this problem that seems simple to me without success on the internet.

In a sample project I've made for the test :
I have a Controller `NotAuthorized`with a `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }`

The `Index` view only contain the text `This page need to be only available in local`.

So, my problem is that, I want that the only way to access `NotAuthorized/Index` is from IIS himself, anybody from LAN or WAN need to get a 403 error.

I think web.config can do the job but is it secured ? and how to implement it ?

It's for a big project, I need to block an API from internet because only the application need to use it.
In the final project, the application use it by local adress like "127.0.0.1/xxx".

*Sorry for my english, not my language.*

**Edit : (following greatbear302 solution)
Tested on a published application with WebDeploy (what I need).**

The site bindings are :

- 192.168.0.5:9999
- testmvc on 192.168.0.5:80

On IIS, I click on my site, and in the Views directory, on my 'NotAuthorized' directory who contain the page I don't want users can access.
On the  IP Address and Domain Restrictions, I've set All deny and 192.168.0.5 (IIS) authorized.

running tests :

- `192.168.0.5:9999/NotAuthorized`: I see the page.
- `testmvc/NotAuthorized` : I see the page.

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Why not just block it in IIS rather than inside your application?

Comment: Maybe because I don't know how to do it ;-)

Comment: Google is your friend :)

Comment: I've tried "url block" in IIS but IIS himself get a `404.5 - Not Found`. Thank you for google, I did not know this site; it's a search engine? /joke_off

Answer (score 0):

In IIS

1. Click on your site
2. Click IP Address and Domain Restrictions (if this feature is missing, install from Add Remove Windows Components in Control Panel)
3. Click Allow Entry on right most pane
4. In Specific IP Address field, enter the IP address of the server hosting your API and click OK
5. Click Edit Feature Settings, in Access for Unspecified Clients, select Deny and click OK

Comment: Already tried. the page is still available.
For the test I use my local IIS on 192.168.0.5 with a dns 'testmvc' on it. I've allow '127.0.0.1' and deny all others like you said but don't look to work.

Comment: Use something other than 127 address. Like 192.168.0.5 or where ever the secured resources lives.

Comment: edit :
It's MVC... I get some tests. If I go on 192.168.0.5:9999/NotAuthorized I can Access the page. fail. But, if I go to 192.168.0.5:9999/Views/NotAuthorized, it work with a beautiful 403 error. Well, I don't know what to do here .

Comment: @Saesee Please clarify: `NotAuthorized` is a test controller which will ultimately be a part of the API you want blocked from public access? Or is `NotAuthorized` controller part of your API **client** and you are trying to block **only that controller**?

Comment: `NotAuthorized` is just my controller name and Index is the function. In other words, I want to block the acces to the `Index` Action in the `NotAuthorized` Controller if you try to access it from anywhere else than IIS himself (localhost). Hope I explained better

Comment: @Saesee I understand `NotAuthorized` is the controller and `Index` is the action within that controller. But can you please clarify what I asked in my previous comment? I'm assuming the `NotAuthorized` controller is part of your API but I want to get it clarified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62388/discussion-between-saesee-and-greatbear302).

Answer (score 0):

Without any success with IIS, I go on a basic IP filtering on the application.

My IIS execute the application on 192.168.0.5 so here my code :

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewBag.UserIP = Request.UserHostAddress;
    if (Request.UserHostAddress != "192.168.0.5")
        throw new HttpException((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Accès non autorisé");
    return View();
}
```

It do the job. I'll see in the future if I can make a better solution for my problem.